# Sliding (or moving) controls in ASP.NET with just javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

Because of how my page is set up, I can not send postBack events and reload the page with controls in new positions.  Therefore, I need to move controls around using javascript.

If I were to have 3 radio buttons on my UI, and when one of the radio buttons is clicked in the list, I want to be able to slide the other radio buttons down and have the clicked radio button show new text boxes, drop down lists, etc, to gain more information from the user.  Code example:
(When no radio buttons are clicked)

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioYes" GroupName="group1" Text="Yes, I'll give you more information."   runat="server" /><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioMaybe" GroupName="group1" Text="Not sure yet." runat="server" /><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioNo" GroupName="group1" Text="Nope." runat="server" /><br />
```

Once the 'yes' radio button is pushed, I want to have 'maybe' and 'no' slide down and leave room as if I had this coded up:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioYes" GroupName="group1" Text="Yes, I'll give you more information."   runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="labelName" Text="Name" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioMaybe" GroupName="group1" Text="Not sure yet." runat="server" /><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioNo" GroupName="group1" Text="Nope." runat="server" /><br />
```

And the opposite effect could happen too: When 'yes' is unclicked, the radio buttons slide back up.

Comment: do you have knowledge using jquery?

Comment: where are the 2 element(label and textbox) come from?are they already exists in the page or created dynamic?your description more like to move the new elements to the radio which is chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use jQuery slideToggle(),or ajaxtoolkit PopupControl http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx
My english is very poor ,But if you want have slide down you can use this.

Comment: slideToggle() seems to be working for me.  I am still working on having those controls be 'hidden' (where the 'slider' is slide close) on pageLoad.  Thanks for the answer!